# Codeigniter Html Email Display HTML Source Code

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, codeigniter-3

Try To Send email But It Mailed Format is HTML Source Code.
Here is mY Controller-

```
$config = Array(        
        'protocol' => 'SMTP',
        'smtp_host' => 'hostname',
        'smtp_port' => 'portname',
        'smtp_user' => 'abn@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass' => '***',
        'smtp_timeout' => '4',
        'mailtype'  => 'html',
        'charset'   => 'utf-8'
    );
    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

    $this->email->from('devendra@gmail.com', 'ABC');
    $data = array(
         'userName'=> $this->input->post('email'),
         'password'=> $this->input->post('password'),
         'EmpName'=> $this->input->post('name'),
         'Number'=> $this->input->post('number'),
         'City'=> $this->input->post('city'),
         'State'=> $this->input->post('email'),
         'Address'=> $this->input->post('address')
             );
    $this->email->to($this->input->post('email')); 
    $Subject = 'User Login Details';
    $this->email->subject($Subject); 

    $body = $this->load->view('mailFormat.php',$data,TRUE);
    $this->email->message($body);   
    $this->email->send();
```

and Email Format Page mailFormat.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Employee Registration</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
<body>
<div>
 <div style="font-size: 26px;font-weight: 700;letter-spacing: -0.02em;line-height: 32px;color: #41637e;font-family: sans-serif;text-align: center" align="center" id="emb-email-header"><img style="border: 0;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;display: block;Margin-left: auto;Margin-right: auto;max-width: 152px" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/images/logo.png" alt="WFT" width="152" height="108"></div>

 <p style="Margin-top: 0;color: #565656;font-family: Georgia,serif;font-size: 16px;line-height: 25px;Margin-bottom: 25px">Hey  <?php echo $EmpName;?>,</p> 
<p>Email Id - <?php echo $userName; ?> </p>
<p>Password - <?php echo $password; ?> </p>
<p>Contact Number - <?php echo $Number; ?> </p>
<p>City - <?php echo $City; ?> </p>
<p>State - <?php echo $State; ?> </p>
<p>Address - <?php echo $Address; ?> </p>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Email Sent. but The Format of email Showing HTML Source Code. How to Change it To HTML format email.

Comment: i am using codeIgniter email library. can you please show me. how to write in above code @cakil

Comment: Oops sorry, I'm wrong, then maybe @Snickers have an answer

Comment: @cakil you have marked this question As Duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->email->mailtype('html'); // This was incorrect, check below for what I used
```

[Codeigniter Email Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html)

Here is one method I used a while back, hope it helps

```
    //Setting up the email
    $config = array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'smtp.host.com',
    'smtp_port' => 587,
    'smtp_user' => '******',
    'smtp_pass' => '******',
    'mailtype'  => 'html',
    'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
);
    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

    $data = array(
    'email'    => $user->user_email,
    'username' => $user->user_first_name,
    'token'    => $token,
);
    $this->email->from('*******', 'Title');
    $this->email->to($user->user_email);

    $this->email->subject('***** - Password Reset Request');
    $html = $this->load->view('help/email/forgot_password', $data, true);
    $this->email->message($html);

    $this->email->send();
```

So I think setting it to a variable first is what I did to fix it.

Comment: showing error undefined method CI_Email::mailtype()

Comment: You might need to initialize it, there used to be a bug with CI 2.0.3, I'm not really sure which version you are running, though you can probably try to setup the mailtype using this

$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->initialize(array(
'mailtype' => 'html'
));

Comment: thanks. I used the same code but it won't works for me.

Comment: I've used it in production, so it definitely works on my end, perhaps your mail server is set to strip tags, or is configured to make sure it only sends text emails.

Comment: I think you are right. i have to check server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **mailtype** configuration as already said, but here you have more details and how you should do it right.

**Setting Email Preferences**

> There are 21 different preferences available to tailor how your email
>   messages are sent. You can either set them manually as described here,
>   or automatically via preferences stored in your config file, described
>   below:
>
> Preferences are set by passing an array of preference values to the
>   email initialize method. Here is an example of how you might set some
>   preferences:

```
$config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
$config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

$config['mailtype'] = 'html';         // use this setting

$this->email->initialize($config);
```

[Email Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html#setting-email-preferences)